# Switch Between two web apps using web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have two different apps on two different servers. I want to login one of my app without using login form on other app. I guess i can do this by using `web api`. Any idea what would be the best way for it.

Comment: Use token-based authentication. Intro: [building scalable microservices](http://nordicapis.com/decouple-user-identity-from-api-design-to-build-scalable-microservices/)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy is it possible that if the 2nd app have login page but i want to redirect my query string data without displaying that page.

Comment: and will it work well with asp.net cause i am not using mvc framework here